# VS Mac upgrade to 7.2 (build 636) MonoDevelop.CSharp.Project.CSharpProject exception

Tags: xamarin, installation

I just did a stable update of VS Mac Community Edition this morning. The current version shown is 7.2 (build 636). I added the entire About Details below. I'm not sure what specific version I upgraded from, but it was the most recent version before this as I stay up to date.

After doing the upgrade, which worked without displaying an error, I get this message when opening an iOS solution:

> Error while trying to load the project '/path/to/project.csproj'. The
>   type initializer for 'MonoDevelop.CSharp.Project.CSharpProject' threw
>   an exception.

After dismissing that message, I get another error message with a list of this same error message:

> The type initializer for
>   'MonoDevlop.ide.TypeSystem.MonoDevelopWorkspace' threw an exception.

I did a reboot of the machine, and I still see the error. My next step is to do a complete uninstall/reinstall, but before I do, can someone recommend a less time-consuming approach for diagnosing and fixing this error?

About Details

> === Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac ===
>
> Version 7.2 (build 636) Installation UUID:
>   56e643f6-0a84-4995-b464-438c06eb25ee Runtime:     Mono 5.4.0.201
>   (2017-06/71277e78f6e) (64-bit)    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
>
> Package version: 504000201
>
> === NuGet ===
>
> Version: 4.3.1.4445
>
> === .NET Core ===
>
> Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet Runtime Versions:
>     2.0.0
>     1.1.1
>     1.0.4 SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/Sdks SDK Versions:
>     2.0.0
>     1.0.3 MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks
>
> === Xamarin.Profiler ===
>
> Version: 1.5.6 Location: /Applications/Xamarin
>   Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler
>
> === Xamarin.Android ===
>
> Version: 8.0.0.33 (Visual Studio Community) Android SDK:
>   /Users/danmiser/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
>     Supported Android versions:
>         6.0 (API level 23)
>
> SDK Tools Version: 25.2.5 SDK Platform Tools Version: 26.0.0 SDK Build
>   Tools Version: 25.0.3
>
> Java SDK: /usr java version "1.8.0_101" Java(TM) SE Runtime
>   Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
>
> Android Designer EPL code available here:
>   https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL
>
> === Xamarin Inspector ===
>
> Version: 1.3.2 Hash: 461f09a Branch: 1.3-release Build date: Tue, 03
>   Oct 2017 18:26:57 GMT Client compatibility: 1
>
> === Apple Developer Tools ===
>
> Xcode 9.0 (13247) Build 9A235
>
> === Xamarin.iOS ===
>
> Version: 11.2.0.11 (Visual Studio Community) Hash: 2f8bbec0 Branch:
>   d15-4-xi Build date: 2017-10-05 20:56:05-0400
>
> === Xamarin.Mac ===
>
> Version: 3.8.0.49 (Visual Studio Community)
>
> === Build Information ===
>
> Release ID: 702000636 Git revision:
>   b349c8fc0c2e1aab0179917d56eed75eb3a03337 Build date: 2017-10-06
>   15:20:04-04 Xamarin addins: a8da992c78f7eb65b3cdb3f951c34a30337cab35
>   Build lane: monodevelop-lion-d15-4
>
> === Operating System ===
>
> Mac OS X 10.12.6 Darwin 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0
>       Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017
>       root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
>
> === Enabled user installed addins ===
>
> MFractor 3.00.16

Comment: Doing a complete uninstall, including Mono, as per this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/uninstall and reinstalling fixed the error. I'm not doing this as the answer in case someone else comes along to figure out what the true cause was/is.

Comment: After successfully opening my solution after the reinstall, I quit VS. When I reopened VS and then tried to open my project again, I now have the same error. So a reinstall doesn't solve this.

Comment: It was MFractor causing the issue. Here's a link of someone talking about this on the Xamarin forums:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/104697/visual-studio-for-mac-7-2-build-636-unable-to-open-existing-project-after-upgrade?

Comment: Hi guys, we are looking into this. Please get in touch with me at matthew@mfractor.com if you need support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure that you have MFractor extension 'Updated' or Uninstalled. That work for me.

Check:
Visual Studio Community Menu (Top) -> Extensions.... -> Upgrades Tab

- Open Extension Editor

[image: Open Extension Editor]

- Check Upgrades (I remove the extension)

[image: I remove the extension and work for me !!!]

Comment: Hi Luis, what version of MFractor were you on prior to uninstalling it? If we've caused issues in your dev environment, we need to fix them :)

Comment: I receive email with critical update. 

http://mfractor.us13.list-manage.com/track/click?u=866158240431148a938c08ba3&id=2f00228bf9&e=f7163c05c0

Comment: Glad to hear Luis! Please reach out to me if you need any further assistance: matthew@mfractor.com

Comment: Thank you @LuisAbreuAcevedo this was the solution! I removed mFractor now forever!!